# Storing value with size greater than column size

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to discuss an approach: 
We've a **count** column in oracle table. Dataype of column is `char(3 Byte)`. On each insertion of a row, the value of count column increment by 1(But it is not an identity column).

There is a possibility that value will go beyond **999**. So how can we handle it.
Till now, the approach I'm able to justified is:

Increasing the column datatype at runtime. Steps are:

1. First, we'll check the length of value.
2. For eg, if length is 4 then Alter the column of table and change the size of column to `char(4 BYTE)`

Any better approach you people can provide...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if it is count, I suppose it is a number. Why you use char datatype?

Comment: Use a numeric column type, or use an arbitrary large char whose size will not likely be exceeded.

Comment: **Never**, ever store numbers in `char` or `varchar` columns (and `varchar` is always a better choice than `char`)

Comment: At all times use VARCHAR2 instead of CHAR or VARCHAR. (VARCHAR should never be used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Increasing the column datatype at runtime.

It proves that the **design is flawed**. You should never modify a table at runtime.

In your requirement, there is no reason to store the **NUMBER** as a **STRING**. This will be for sure the primary reason for degraded performance. You should chose proper **data types**, which in your case should be **NUMBER**.

> On each insertion of a row, the value of count column increment by 1

You should ideally be using a **sequence** for this. Depending on your database version, there are two options:

- Pre 12c releases - See [**trigger-sequence approach**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/)
- 12c onward - See [**IDENTITY column**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/)

On a side note, **CHAR** datatype stores fixed-length character strings. You should ideally use **VARCHAR2** datatype, which stores variable-length character strings.

Answer (score 0):

You really, really shouldn't be storing numbers in a char or varchar column. If at all possible, refactor the table design that's got you into this problem.

If you can't do that, are you sure the column can't be changed from char(3) to something more useful? Char(4) is only 1 byte more storage, varchar(4) would probably be no extra storage usually if char(3) has been working elsewhere.

If you *really* can't do any of them and you're still stuck in this pickle and you've absolutely got to get a number over 999 into a char(3) column even after kicking and screaming that it's not a good idea....

Store it in hex. Note this *very* clearly or it'll confuse people, but hex to decimal conversion isn't that much of a black art and it'll give you a range up to 4095 in the same character space.